# trying to set the default value of useState with useSelector but it doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, use-state

I was trying to get my state with useSelector and when I console.log it I get my data perfectly but when I try to put that data in useState my value stays empty
this is my code :

```
const settings = useSelector((state) => state.getsettings);
console.log("SETTINGS ==>", settings.info);``
const [getValue, setValue] = useState(settings.info.fulfilmentAutoma);
```

my "getValue" is empty while my "settings.info.fulfilmentAuto" is not!

[image]

any help please ?!

Comment: ```useState``` is only initialized in the first render, you need to use ```useState``` setter to update the state value.

Comment: I want to set the useState value immidiately after getting the state can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 setValue(settings.info.fulfilmentAutoma);
});
```

Comment: this is my useEffect :
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("STORE SETTINGS...");
    dispatch(getSettings());
  }, []);

can I add the setValue even when I'm dispatching ?

Comment: if the deps array is empty, it means the ```useEffect``` will be executed only once.

Comment: yes I copied the useEffect you sent me but the value didn't change :/ still empty